# How to display the field when the behaviour is containable?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have containable behavior in my model I have an array like that

```
  [0] => Array
    (
        [Post] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [title] => First article
                [content] => aaa
                [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
            )
        [Comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [post_id] => 1
                        [author] => Daniel
                        [email] => dan@example.com
                        [website] => http://example.com
                        [comment] => First comment
                        [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [post_id] => 1
                        [author] => Sam
                        [email] => sam@example.net
                        [website] => http://example.net
                        [comment] => Second comment
                        [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                    )
            )
        [Tag] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Awesome
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Baking
                    )
            )
    )
```

How can I display the value of fields in my view? like I want to display the value of

```
    [Post][title]
    [Comment][post_id]
    [Comment][author]
```

how can I do this, please help me to do that I m new in cakephp, I don't know how to do that, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think its a cakephp question at all. Try "learning basic array iteration !!!"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($posts as $post){

 foreach($post['Comment'] as $comment){
   /*Display start here*/
     $post['Post']['title'];
     $comment['post_id'];
     $comment['author'];

 }

}
```

Hope this help...

Comment: you forget one thing foreach($post as $post){ $post['Post']['id']then the another for each loop will start in above for each loop, hope u got it

Comment: Hi you can call $post['Post']['id'] inside the second foreach also , please look the post title is called like that, the only issue that it will show the post id (if we call inside the second foreach) as number of comments